# What am I doing wrong on this Python coding, when it shows the ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-2.5'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting this error.  What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
num = input('Enter positive integer: ')

try:
    print(int(num))
except:
    print('Error: You did not enter a positive integer')
else:                    # else is executed if no errors were raised
    print('Integer input accepted')
finally:                    # always executes at the end of the try-except block
    print('the try block is completed')


if int(num) > 1:
    for i in range(2,int(num)):
        
    # for loop is used, iterate from 2 to n / 2 
    
        # nested if statement is used to see it's a prime or not:
        if (int(num)% i)== 0:
            print('It is a composite')
            break
        else:
            print('It is a prime')
            break
elif (int(num) ==0 or int(num) ==1):
    print('It is neither prime nor composite')
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-049b0b9078db> in <module>
     11 
     12 
---> 13 if int(num) > 1:
     14     for i in range(2,int(num)):
     15 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-2.5'
```

Comment: You're trying to parse `-2.5` as an int. Like the error message says.

Comment: it's  ```float``` not ```int```, try ```float(num)```

Comment: Even your first line tells you that you want positive integers instead of negatives. There are no checks for your int input conversion so it actually accepts negative ints currently.

Comment: The same thing happens when you try to use `int(num)` on line 13 as happened on line 4. After all, `num` did not *change*. Notice how the `print` statement, `print('Error: You did not enter a positive integer')` executed, and you saw that message? Were you expecting the program to just *stop* there, or something? Why?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an interesting point.
Python can parse the string `'-2.5'` as a `float`, but not as an `int`, despite it knowing what to do with `int(-2.5)`, which simply returns the int `-2`.

If you want to only consider the `int` part of a `float` represented as a `string`, you'll have to first parse the string as a `float`, then parse the `float` as an `int`, like so:

```
if int(float(num)) > 1:
    for i in range(2,int(num)):
        ...
```

However, what you may want to do is actually compare the float number and check whether it's greater than 1. In that case you'd simply have to cast the `string` as `float` and compare, like so:

```
if float(num) > 1:
    for i in range(2,int(num)):
        ...
```